# Make invoke search tasks.py in project subfolder

Tags: python, invoke

I am using [Invoke](http://www.pyinvoke.org/) in my project to run some code quality tasks (pylint, pycodestyle, pydocstyle, etc.).

Therefore, I have a file `tasks.py` at the root of my project.

I also have two other repos that will run the same tasks.

Therefore, I would like to share this `tasks.py` file in a submodule git for all the repos.

The problem is that I am unable to make invoke find the `tasks.py` in a subfolder of the project and the documentation is not that clear/I am unfamiliar with the mentioned Config/Context object.

Has anyone faced that problem already?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit dated but I had the same issue myself recently so here it goes:

#### Option 1 - Use a runtime configuration

`invoke` seems to have an option to search [from a different sources root using the -r option](http://Change%20the%20root%20search%20path:%20Configure%20tasks.search_root%20or%20use%20--search-root.%20This%20value%20may%20be%20any%20valid%20directory%20path.). However, this seems [not to work at the time when using configuration files](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/issues/471).

#### Option 2 - Load the nested file as an import

You can try to slightly hack `invoke's` loading options. Assuming your folder structure is this:

```
| repository root:
| ├── some other files/folders
| ├── submodule:
|    ├── tasks.py
|    ├── some other files/folders
```

You can add a `tasks.py` under the repository root

```
| repository root:
| ├── some other files/folders
| ├── tasks.py # new one that we added
| ├── submodule:
|    ├── tasks.py
|    ├── some other files/folders
```

In this new `tasks.py` import the sumbodule `tasks.py` code:

```py
from submodule.tasks import *
```

This will load the content of your nested `tasks.py` into the one in the root and `invoke` will recognize all of it's content. You should be weary of one caveat though, if the nested `tasks.py` uses it's own imports that the parent can't, the tasks might fail in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using namespaces ( https://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/0.11.1/concepts/namespaces.html ).

Add `tools/test.py` as

```py
from invoke import task


@task
def run(c):
    """Running python tests via `pytest`."""
    # `pty=True` makes `pytest`` use colors when executed via `invoke`.
    # Be aware `err_stream` and `stderr` will always be empty when `pty=True`.
    c.run('pytest', pty=True)
```

Add `tasks.py` as

```py
from invoke import Collection
import tools.test

ns = Collection(tools.test)  # `ns` is the namespace
```

```
.
├── tasks.py
└── tools
    └── test.py
```

Show all available tasks via `inv -l`

```bash
Available tasks:

  test.run
```

Execute the `test.run` task via `inv test.run`

````bash
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.8, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Volumes/XTend/Work/Coding/Sandbox
collected 0 items

============================ no tests ran in 0.01s =============================```
````